# How to convert a lambda function to a key argument for the max() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, key, max

I am trying to convert a lambda function in normal function to use it as a key instead but i couldn't understand it.

```
def most_appear(name_list):
     return max(name_list, key=lambda x: name_list.count(x))
```

How this lambda work?
How I can create a function to use as a key?

Comment: This is a terrible way to find the most common element of a list. It's O(n^2) (or precisely, it takes a number of element comparisons quadratic in the size of the input list). Use a `collections.Counter`.

Comment: If you know how to create a function, then you can pass it as key. Simple as that. Or was your question something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function counts the amount for each element and returns the element with most elements. The `lambda` is not necessary, since `name_list.count` already is a function:

```
def most_appear(name_list):
     return max(name_list, key=name_list.count)
```

Comment: Highly Pythonic? I thought so at first, but then realised that it still applies the `count` (O(n)) method to each element. Suppose the list has a million elements. For each value in the list, you iterate over the list in the same way that the OP does.

Answer (score 1):

It's just slightly more convenient syntax for:

```
def func(x):
    return name_list.count(x)
```

and then

```
... max(..., key=func)
```

Comment: I upvoted this slightly reluctantly, because it does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, if you have two arguments for function, you could use partial function

```
from functools import partial
def replace_lambda(lst, item):
    return lst.count(item)

def most_appear(name_list):
     func = partial(replace_lambda, name_list)
     return max(name_list,key=func )
```